# how to remove google + auto back up pictures

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-s-4, google

Is there a way I can remove the auto back up folder from my S4. Its taking up a lot of space for the backup folder of just pictures and I dont want it there.

Answer (score 0):

go to your google+ app, choose settings and the very first thing you get is General Settings - Auto Backup

you can turn that completely off, or you can specify and change the settings of the back up